# Print a R function that loop through 3 arguments and output matching criteria

Tags: r, function, dataframe, loops

I have an excel file that includes student names, zip code, gender, and major. It needs to be written in a function that takes in 3 arguments d for the data (the excel file), z for the zip, and m for the major. The function has to loop through each row in the data and when I call the function, it will print out the names of the student matching zip and major I put in. For example, student_data(student, 12345, Music) will print out:

```
Names   Zip    Major   Gender
John    12345  Music   Male
Jane    12345  Music   Female
```

Here is my code:

```
library(readxl)
student <- read_excel("student")

student_data <- function(d, s, m){
  d <- student
  s <- d$studentname
  m <- d$major
  for (i in 1:nrow(d)){
    return(subset(d, s[i] & m[i])
  }
}

student_data(d, 12345, "Music")
```

When I call this, the output is NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making simple syntax mistakes here.

1. When you use `return`, you're telling the function to end right there, so it does not make sense to have a return inside a loop, because you're only returning the first iteration.
2. Your function takes `s` and `m` as inputs, but then overwrites them with information found in `d`, which means they are not used as inputs at all. I'm assuming you actually want to take as inputs `(d, z, m)` right?
3. If you want to print the rows where there are students with Zip `z` which are enrolled in the `m` major, you could just filter the dataset and print it altogether in two lines. For example:

```
student_data <- function(d, z, m) {
    # select all rows where Zip = z and major == m
    d_filtered <- d[d$Zip == z & d$major == m, ]

    print(d_filtered)
}
```

**NOTE:** The answer may not be totally right because your example provided is a bit confusing. Please edit your question and provide more details if that is the case and I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. This works!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following function. The input is changed to have `z` (for `Zip`), not `s`. It returns a subset of `d` matching the given criteria.

```
student_data <- function(d, z, m){
  i <- d[["Zip"]] == z
  j <- d[["Major"]] == m
  d[i & j, ]
}
```

If the function needs to accept several values for `z` or `m`, rewrite it as

```
student_data <- function(d, z, m){
  i <- d[["Zip"]] %in% z
  j <- d[["Major"]] %in% m
  d[i & j, ]
}
```